# How to take only the text without the json?

Tags: php, json, laravel

In my database, my text is stored like this :

```
{"en":"My super title is fantastic"}
```

I do a foreach for get the value

```
foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $results[] = ['slug' => $query->slug, 'value' => $query->title];
    }
```

But, the result is :

```
{"en":"My super title is fantastic"}
```

And I would like

```
My super title is fantastic
```

How to take only the text without the {} and the locale?

thank you very much

Comment: you can use json decode to transform json in to array and then print it.

Comment: I need the JSON because I retrieve it in Javascript after

Comment: bit confusing now what exactly you want ? do you want test which is not in json format  ?

Answer (score 1):

I need the JSON because I retrieve it in Javascript after – Jeremy 22 hours ago

so you use json_decode();
and then json_encode();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), example:

```
$yourvar = '{"en":"My super title is fantastic"}';
$array = json_decode($yourvar, true);
echo current($array); // is what you need
```